# How do we handle an answer that is no longer accurate?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I'm referring to this question here:

[What does it mean to hydrate an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991135/what-does-it-mean-to-hydrate-an-object)

At the time this question was answered, back in 2011, the term "Hydration" was new.  It is still very young now even, but the use of this term has matured somewhat.  Now it is clear that the fundamental part of the answer, that hydration is a synonym for deserialization, is patently false.  However by now almost three years later it has a bunch of upvotes and is the accepted answer.

This question comes up pretty prominently in google when you search on things like "hydrate an object".  I'm concerned that people visiting the site will see this and be misinformed.  I think it's important that people using StackOverflow to learn have confidence that they are learning correct things.  But this answer is not correct, and I'm concerned because it looks correct on the page.  What can we do to address something like this?

I have downvoted the answer and upvoted the correct answers below it, but there are still 15 votes on the accepted answer, and it is accepted, and only 6 on the next choice.  Is there anything else we can do to address something like this?

**Edit:** I have already communicated with the original poster of the answer, and he doesn't agree with me entirely.  He self-described himself as being "catty or combative" about it.  I do not believe a bounty is appropriate, as two people now (myself being one) have submitted answers below it which have garnered upvotes.  Ideally, I would just edit the answer to improve it, but I'm concerned that the original author will simply revert my changes.

So I'm just not sure the best approach here to deliver a good quality answer to google searchers without starting some kind of an edit war or confrontation.